# splitting phoenix project into applications

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Mix provides functionality to have an umbrella project, where standalone pieces of functionality (apps) can run together, but be loosely coupled and be developed separately.

In my phoenix application I want to move my authentication logic into a separate app in order to reuse it later on. However for my authentication app/module I require model/view/controller functionality from phoenix and I do not want to generate the whole new phoenix project just for that though

What is the best way to achieve that in phoenix?

I have looked at [this thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/two-phoenix-apps-under-umbrella-project/401), however it did not help much.

There is a similar concept in [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086851/how-do-you-divide-your-project-into-applications-in-django), however it is done on the [framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/) level. So there are clear ways to wire up apps inside the project and apps are allowed to have their own model/view/controllers. in phoenix case the situation is different as umbrella project is a mix feature and there are no clear guidelines on how to setup things up in that case.

UPDATE: I have found [this](https://elixirforum.com/t/extending-a-phoenix-application/763) post, which is kind of exactly what I am trying to achieve, just keeping it for reference.

Comment: I think as one way to go you could move most of the logic to the separate app and make it return data that would be handled in your model/view/controller. For example, if you need to redirect users if they access some page that they don't have an access to, you could just make your auth app return `{:error, :no_access}` or something and then handle the error in your controller.

Comment: @JustMichael but it would be nicer if I could have model/view/controller in my auth module and be just able to use it in router.ex with its own namespace, i.e. MyApp.Authentication.RegistrationController