# How to encapsulate code in modules, bundles or plugins?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking for a way to build something comparable to bundle in symfony or a plugin  in CakePHP. For example: in the user module, all the controllers, template and views will be in a single folder so that I can easily access them.

And I want to create similar module based on functionality, for example, payment module, inventory module etc.

In present architecture, I can keep all controllers together, all views together. As my project is very large, so now it has almost 140 controllers and so on and it looks very messy to me. What does phoenix provide for modular code?

Comment: There is no clean way to do it as I know. Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249813/splitting-phoenix-project-into-applications

Comment: Having the same troubles on the project! Controllers should be probably put to folder which represents some 'bundle'

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, check this [link](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/adding-pages), but I also strongly advice you to check very well prepared book written by creator of Phoenix, creator of Elixir and guys, who knows at least 14 languages - "Programming in Phoenix".

Phoenix has way much different structure than Symfony or any other framework, because it simply consists of functions. You don't have black-box middleware, but you can create anything you need.

Phoenix handle requests in that order:

```
your request in browser
|> Endpoint (in lib folder)
|> Router (as the rest in web folder)
|> Pipeline (set of Plug functions in router as well)
|> Controller
```

Then controller uses view (instead of middleware you can define functions, which you want to have enabled when rendering templates) and templates - just a placeholders for HTML tags.

The best idea for the beginning the great journey with Phoenix is to obey conventions. Whenever you want to add new action you have to:

- add new entry in router (in `router.ex`)
- add new controller or use existing one (in web/controllers)
- add new view or use existing one (in web/views)
- add new template or use existing one (in web/templates)

Good luck.